# Replace method implementation in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to replace method implementation with parent implementation:

```
//  Get superclass's valueDisplayText()
//  XLFormSelectorCell is a parent of HCFormSelectorCell
//  HCFormSelectorCell - swift class
//  XLFormSelectorCell - obj-c class
let impParent = class_getMethodImplementation(XLFormSelectorCell.self, Selector("valueDisplayText"))
let method = class_getInstanceMethod(HCFormSelectorCell.self, Selector("valueDisplayText"))
method_setImplementation(method, impParent)
class_replaceMethod(HCFormSelectorCell.self, Selector("valueDisplayText"), impParent, method_getTypeEncoding(method))
```

But instead in replaces `parent` implementation with subclass implementation.
Why and how to achieve desired?

**P.S:** The reason I'm doing this: I need to call parent class's hidden method (obj-c class). Any other approaches to do this?

Comment: what do you mean by "hidden method?" You don't need swizzling just to call private methods in ObjC. Just declare them and call them. (The above isn't a typical way of swizzling. Search for "method swizzling" for many discussions about it. It is of course strongly discouraged in production code, since it's very fragile.)

Comment: @RobNapier In ObjC it would be simple, but how to declare method for parent class in swift?